# How do I use ScrollSpy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to build my website and I'd really like to have some font awesome glyphs on my page that fade in when I scroll. The thing is that I do not really understand Spyscroll or how to use it.

Here is my code, perhaps anyone could help me out.

```css
#section2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 105%;
}
html {

}
p{
    color: white;
}
.servicetitle{
    color: white;
}
.btn-light{
    color:white;
}
#onzespecialiteiten {
text-align: center;
    margin-top: -5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 200%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <title>Exodius Webdesign</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Add smooth scrolling to all links
            $("a").on('click', function(event) {

                // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
                if (this.hash !== "") {
                    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Store hash
                    var hash = this.hash;

                    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                    // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                    }, 800, function(){

                        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                        window.location.hash = hash;
                    });
                } // End if
            });
        });
    </script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a style="color: #ffffff" class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Exodius Webdesign</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class=""><a style="color: #ffffff" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a style="color: #ffffff" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a style="color: #ffffff" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a style="color: #ffffff" href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a style="color: #ffffff" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target="col-md-3 col-sm-6" data-offset="60" style="background-color: #293B4D; height: 200%">

<!-- Content van home -->
<h1 style="margin-top: 15%; margin-left: 55%; color: white; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;" >Exodius Webdesign</h1>
<p style="margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 30%; text-align: center; color: white; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
<img src="images/logotransparant.png" alt="logo" height="560" width="960" style="margin-left: -5%; margin-top: -12%">

<!-- Dit is de button en de section waarnaar die naartoe scrollt -->
<a href="#section2" class="btn" id="butonn" type="button" style="background-color: #ffffff; color:black; margin-left: -2%; margin-bottom: 17%; border-radius: 14px; width: 250px">Lees meer</a>

<div id="section2">
    <section></section>
</div>

<!-- Dit is het blauwe vlak -->
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 5%; height: 790px; background-color: #3692D0">
    <div  style="margin: 10%; text-align: center" class="row">
        <p id="onzespecialiteiten">Onze Specialiteiten</p>
        <hr width="25%" style="margin-left: 38%; margin-top: 2%"><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >

            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-zoom" >
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                <h4 class="servicetitle">
                    <strong>Webdesign</strong>
                </h4>
                <p>Wij bouwen binnen één week een website met Wordpress of Bootstrap</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Lees Meer</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-zoom" style="animation-delay: 0.1s;">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                <h4 class="servicetitle">
                    <strong>Photoshop</strong>
                </h4>
                <p>Wij kunnen vrijwel met alle Photoshop opdrachten overweg</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Lees Meer</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-zoom" style="animation-delay: 0.12s;">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                <h4 class="servicetitle">
                    <strong>Webshops</strong>
                </h4>
                <p>Wij kunnen met Wordpress CMS complete Webshops bouwen</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Lees Meer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-zoom" style="animation-delay: 0.13s;">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                <h4 class="servicetitle">
                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                </h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#buttonn").click(function() {
$('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use w3schools (they tend to be less reliable for information), instead use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

Check this one link and the next videos, you will get the idea

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2qjgCRkmt8&index=47&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXd4xnk-j5FGhHjUv1LsF0V